# Are constant functions continuous in constructive mathematics?

Tags: general-topology, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic, locales

The standard proof that a constant function $c: X \to Y$, $x \mapsto y_0$ is continuous proceeds as follows: if $U \subseteq Y$ is open, then either $c^{-1}(U)=X$ if $y_0 \in U$, or $c^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$ if $y_0 \notin U$. Either way, $c^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Since this proof apparently uses excluded middle, it is not valid as written in constructive mathematics. But constant functions ought to be continuous, so what is the correct proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set $\{0 : c \in U\}$. Classically, this set is empty if $c \not\in U$ and a singleton if $c \in U$, but intuitionistically, it may not be either.

Nonetheless, we can define a family of sets on $A$. For $a \in A$ let $X_a$ be $X$.

Now $c^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{a \in A} X_a$ which is a union of open sets, so is open.

Comment: Thanks! Just wondering what you mean by $\{0: c \in U \}$?

Comment: It's the set that contains $0$ precisely if $c \in U$. Depending on your exact axioms, it should be constructible with set comprehension.

Comment: Ah ok. I'm trying to self-teach HoTT, so I'm trying to think (informally so far) in the context of Martin-Lof intuitionistic type theory.

Comment: In MLTT, you'd have $U$ given by a predicate on $X$ (say $U: X \to \Omega$ — in HoTT, $\Omega$ is usually just called Prop). The equivalent of $A$ would then be the sigma type $\Sigma_{x: 1} U(c)$. An element of this type is thus an element of the unit type $1$ together with a proof that $c$ is in $U$. And so, if $c$ isn't in $U$, it's empty. If it is and elements of $\Omega$ are proof-irrelevant, then it's a singleton type. Of course, using $A = U(c)$ directly would also work in this setup.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in f^{-1}[O]$. Then $c=f(x) \in O$. If now $x' \in X$ is arbitrary, $c=f(x') \in O$ as well. It follows that $f^{-1}[O]=X$, which is open.

Put alternatively, for any $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ we have a neighbourhood (namely $X$) that sits inside it. So **all** points of $f^{-1}[O]$ are interior points. QED.

Comment: Why can you assume that either $f^{-1}[O]$ is empty or there exists $x \in f^{-1}[O]$? (basically, what rule are you using to conclude $(f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset) \lor (f^{-1}[O]=X)$ from the previous step?)

Comment: @SCappella How do you define the empty set in constructive logic? By definition you can only show a set to be empty constructively if the assumption it is has an element leads to a contradiction. You have to be careful: empty, finite, infinite etc. all have slightly different definitions depending on the school of constructivism you follow. Logic deduction rules vary too. It's complicated.

Comment: Ok, so you start from the assumption that $x \in f^{-1}[O]$ and conclude that $f^{-1}[O] = X$. Why does that tell you that $(f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset) \lor (f^{-1}[O]=X)$. I see an application of LEM there. To get a contradiction, you'd need another assumption.

Comment: @SCappella and the argument in the last paragraph? Do you agree with that? I take any point in $f^{-1}[O]$ and show its interior. Doesn't that make $f^{-1}[O]$ open **by definition**?

Comment: It works, though whether it's by definition depends on your definition of open set.

Comment: @SCappella Well, you have to start with the definitions,  right? I don't want to do maths in a world where open does not mean the same as all points are interior points, and I cannot prove a universal statement by showing something for an arbitrary element, as I did.

Comment: Yes, like I said, it works. There's no problem with either of those things. Though axiomizing open sets directly (i.e. arbitrary unions and finite intersections are open) is also common. The problem with what you had originally is that $(f^{-1}[O] = \emptyset) \lor (f^{-1}[O]=X)$ implies [LPO](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+omniscience) and so is intuitionistically invalid (take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $U = \mathbb{R}_{<0} \cup \mathbb{R}_{>0}$)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104871/discussion-between-scappella-and-henno-brandsma).

Comment: The following proof of one part of the equivalence works intuitionistically: if $U$ satisfies that $U$ is a neighborhood of every point of $U$ (where my definition of neighborhood doesn't require it to be open), then $U$ is equal to the union of open $V$ with $V \subseteq U$.